# jquery mobile old value instead of new

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm sending a variable via link:

```
<a href="foo.php?var=101"> php </a>
<a href="foo.php?var=102"> html </a>
<a href="foo.php?var=102"> css </a>
```

and on `foo.php`:

```
<!-- this part is under data-role="page" !-->
if(isset($_GET['var'])){
    switch($_GET['var']){
        case "101":
            setcookie("bar", "1");
            break;
        case "102":
            setcookie("bar", "2");
            break;
        case "103":
            setcookie("bar", "3");
            break;
        default:
            setcookie("bar", "");
    }
}
<!-- this part is under contents !-->

echo $_COOKIE['bar'];
```

now the problem is:  lets say Im on `index.php` and I click on link `php`, i get nothing on `foo.php`, if I go back and click `html` I get `php` which is unusual, same if i go back and click on `css` after that, I get `html`

all my JS files are under `index.php`'s head, why am I getting the old value?

Comment: what is ur question?

Comment: @MohitJain , I thought it was obvious but I edited it and added a few words at end of question for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that setcookie() doesn't set the cookies immediately, it sends the headers so the browser sets the cookies. This means that, for the current page load, setcookie() will no generate any $_COOKIE.

When the browser later on requests a page, it sends the cookies in the headers so the PHP can retrieve them in the form of $_COOKIE.

Comment: i know JQM doent load header everytime, but is there a way to bypass this? I really want to set it as cookie and load it as some operations on the page depend on it

Comment: when you are creating cookies,you can save cookie data in variable and can use that variable like $data="bar"; setcookie($data, "1");echo $data;